# Which is correct : "on the table that you told me about" or "which you told on the table about"?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> I got on the table the book that you told me about.
>   I got the book that you told me about.was on the table.

Here which sentence is correctly speaking in English conversation?

My point is to highlight that I got the book and the book is on the table as someone told me.  After getting the book, which sentence would I use to tell someone that I got it?

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your sentences is correct.

Here are some correct sentences:

> I have (here|there) on the table the book you told me about.
>
> I have the book you told me about (here|there) on the table.